# JPA: embedded an embeddable entity with embeddedid inside it

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have an entity that embed another entity with an embeddeid inside it. When i use the first entity i get this exception:

```
it.test.tesctclassPK must not have @Id properties when used as an @EmbeddedId: it.test.firstClass.test.id
```

but in the key class there is no @id annotation and not even in the embedded class.

## Edit

Firstclass is the not embedded class, test is the embeddable class and testpk is the embeddeid of the embeddable class.

## Edit 2

FirstClass

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "sometable", schema = "someschema")
public class FirstClass implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private FirstClassPK id;
    @Embedded
    private Test test;
    public FirstClass() {
    }
    /*various attribute getters and setters*/
}
```

Test

```
@Entity
@Table(name="sometable", schema="somechema")
@Embeddable
public class Test implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private TestPK id;
    public Test() {
    }

    @EmbeddedId
    public TestPK getId() {
        return this.id;
    }
    /*various attribute, getters and setters*/
}
```

TestPk

```
Test

@Entity
@Table(name="sometable", schema="somechema")
@Embeddable
public class TestPk implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public TestPk() {
    }

    /*various attribute, getters and setters*/
}
```

Comment: could you please add more details, replace **** with actuals

Comment: the ***** is packages name, i'll put fake name

Comment: can you share your class declaration atleast

Comment: i've added some information, do you need something about the class?

Comment: class definitions ease understanding

Comment: updated with class written

Comment: why are your tagging this entity-framework ?

Comment: wrong tag, i'd corrected it

Comment: Is there any field/property is TestPk that is annotated with @Id? I wonder there is, because you annotated TestPk with @Entity, then it must have an id.